# What is proper practice for performance rules testing?

Tags: performance, unit-testing, version-control, integration-testing

I know that what we're doing is incorrect/strange practice.

We have an object that is constructed in many places in the app, and lags in its construction can severely impact our performance.

We want a gate to stop check-ins which affect this construction's performance too adversely... 
So what we did was create a unit test which is basically the following:

```
myStopwatch.StartNew()
newMyObject = New myObject()
myStopwatch.Stop()
Assert(myStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds < 100)
```

Or: **Fail if construction takes longer than 100ms**

This "works" in the sense that check-ins will not commit if they impact this performance too negatively... However it's inherently a bad unit test because it can fail intermittently... If, for example, our build-server happens to be slow for whatever reason.

In response to some of the answers; we explicitly want our gates to reject check-ins that impact this performance, we don't want to check logs or watch for trends in data.

What is the correct way to meter performance in our check-in gate?

Comment: These should probably be done by ratio rather than a hard-number. Or it will be heavily dependent on the speed of the test machine.

Comment: Ostracize the last developer who makes an offending check-in.  Possible solutions include: A dorky hat, singing a Britney Spears song out loud, or make him walk in to a biker bar with a pink pony t-shirt: http://djangopony.com/.

Comment: Interesting question. You should consider cashe warming rounds before checking performance, run several tests in row and picking the best result (as you could encounter random OS calls, interruptions, etc.). But that are only my ideas for discusion.

Comment: @Mysticial how do you suggest we do it "by ratio" ?

Comment: You would need to measure the times between an old version and after a change has been made. Then raise a flag when you see a significant regression. This will take some work though, since you have to record the measurements.

Comment: @Mysticial then we're in the same boat as Augusto in his answer... it allows performance to get slower, just as long as it's incremental along check-ins....

Comment: You can fix that by declaring a base-line version that will be held constant for a long time. So you compare all the back to the first version (or something like that) and not just the previous version.

Comment: @Mysticial so say my threshold was 10%, why wouldn't I just change my time to `110ms` instead of `100ms` and attain the same goal?

Comment: If you change machines, then all these hard numbers won't be applicable anymore. I'm not entirely sure what your goal is. If you're building a GUI and you want to make sure that the response time is less than 100ms, then hard-coding that is fine. (as long as your test machine is representative of what the users will use)

Comment: @Mysticial yes I know that if I change machines the numbers are invalid. That's kinda the point of the question. What is the proper way to meter performance on checkins?

Comment: I wouldn't know then. I do mainly HPC, so I measure speedups instead of regressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To avoid the machine dependence, you could first time the construction of a "reference object" which has a known acceptable construction time.     Then compare the time to construct your object to the reference object's time.

This may help prevent false failures on an overloaded server since the reference code will also be slower.  I'd also run the test several times and only require X% of them to pass.  (since there are many external events which can slow down code, but none that will speed it up. )

Answer (score 1):

First I would say: Can't you allow some of that logic be lazily run rather than executing all of it in the constructor / initialization? Or can you partition the object? An useful metric for this is [LCOM4](http://www.aivosto.com/project/help/pm-oo-cohesion.html).

Secondly, can you cache those instances? In a previous project we had a similar situation, and we decided to cache the object for a few minutes. This brought some other smaller issues, but the performance of the app skyrocketed.

And last, I do think it's a good approach, but I would take an average, rathen than just one sample (the OS might just at that time decide to run something else and it might take more than 100ms).
Also, one issue with this approach is, if you update your hardware and forget to update this, you might add even more logic, without realizing.

I think a better approach, but more a bit more tricky to implement, is to store how long it takes to run N iterations, and if that value increases more than X% you fail the build. The benefit of this, is that since you store how long it takes, you can generate a graph from it and see the trend.

Comment: Even if I *could* change this particular constructor or how it is used that would be outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Matt, I put the three things I would do before doing a test like this. I think that the concrete answer to your question is the last paragrapth of the answer.

Comment: say I set the threshold at 10%, now each subsequent check-in can increase the time be 10% and where am I after three check-ins? You are also requiring that I store previous-check-in data somewhere... How can I integrate that information into a unit test or checkin gate?

Comment: About the 10% continuous increase, you're correct, that's why you would need to check the trend. To store it from the test, I think I would store it in a DB (timestamp, hostname and how long it took), and generate the trend from there. The hostname is because you might run this from several build nodes, which might report different timings. Unfortunately, there's no OOTB for your problem, so you'll need to be creative :).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that you should really do this in such a way as to block check ins because it is too much work to be done during the check in process.  Check ins need to be fast because your developers can do nothing else whilst they run.

This unit test would have to compile and run whilst the developer sits and waits for it.  As you pointed out, one iteration of the test is not good enough to produce consistant results.  How many times would it need to be run to be reliable?  10? A run of 10 iterations would increase the check in time by up to 1 second and still isn't reliable enough in my opinion.  If you increased that to 100 iterations you'd get a better result but that's adding 10 seconds to the check in time.

Also, what happens if two developers check in code at the same time?  Does the second one have to wait for the first test to complete before theirs starts or would the tests be run simultaneously?  The first scenario is bad because the second developer has to wait twice as long.  The second scenario is bad as you'd be likely to fail both tests.

I think that a better option would have the unit test be run after the check in has completed and, if it fails, have it communicate this to somebody.  You could have the test run after each check in but that still has the potential for two people to check in at the same time.  I think that it would be better to run the test every N minutes.  That way you'd be able to track it down fairly quickly.

You **could** do it so that it blocks check ins but you'd have to make sure that it only runs when that object (or a dependancy) changes so that don't slow down every commit.  You'd also have to make sure that the test isn't run more than once at a time.

As to the specific test, I don't think that you can get away with anything other than run the test through a number of iterations to get a more accurate result.  I wouldn't like to rely on anything less than a 5 or 10 second test (so 50 to 100 iterations).

Comment: We do not allow any checkins to commit unless all unit tests pass. This is pretty standard policy. What *isn't* standard is performance-metering unit tests... hence my question.